# Classroom assessment tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, database

I want to create an HTML file which pulls information from one of several possible databases.

The database will consist of students names and target grades and there will be one for each class.

The page created will effectively have a block/button for each student with a drop down box  which contains a grade.

I would like to send this data to another database (one for each class) to track progress over time, effectively when submitting the classes grades I want to add a coloumn to the database

I have been learning programming for the last 12 months and have a reasonable understanding of HTML, JavaScript, Python (I have also just started leanring some jquery) . I dont want a full fledged solution but if someone could point me in the right direction I would  be happy to do the hard work.

Primary question is what language do I need to learn to code read and write to the database? Any other suggestions about scripting are more than welcome.

Comment: python services are probably the way you want to go... but this isn't really a mortarboard for asking how best to do a website... look up a tutorial for writing services in python

Comment: You can write your server in python, or in Javascript with Node.js

Comment: MySQL is the way to go.

Comment: @RenéRoth: PostgreSQL is the way to go. Or Oracle. Or Mongo. etc. etc. Everyone has their favourite, but it *really depends on the circumstances, use cases and existing expertise*. Just spouting an opinion without meaningful context is why this type of question gets closed.

Comment: MySQL tends to be the easiest and most compatible solution for beginners. Especially seeing how OP has been learning programming for 12 months and yet still hasn't even heard about database software. You said yourself it depends on circumstances and existing expertise - so yes, MySQL seems to be the straightforward solution in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the  input, sorry for infringing the rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use PHP and Javascript (jQuery is a easy to use framework). PHP can handle the "backend" operations like reading and writing to the database. HTML / CSS / Javascript can handle the view.

If you want to do all of this without the annoying page refreshes you can take a look at AJAX.

Some links to help you getting started

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php
- http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/getting-started/